# Using superfasthash in Java

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I am testing the speed comparison between superfasthash and the default hashing algorithm used in Java.

But I'm not sure if I'm using the superfasthash algo correctly as I can't really find any documentation on what the params mean.

I got the java impl of the algo [here](https://github.com/Arisotura/Whitehole/blob/master/src/whitehole/SuperFastHash.java).

This is my code:

```
public class Main
{

   static List<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {

      writeToArray();
      System.out.println("Finished writing to the array.");

      //hashing using default java
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();
      dataArray.stream()
               .forEach(s -> s.hashCode());
      long endTime = System.nanoTime();
      long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
      System.out.println("Finished hashing the file using default java (nanoseconds): " + duration );

      //hashing using superfasthash algo
      startTime = System.nanoTime();
      dataArray.stream()
               .forEach(s -> {
                  SuperFastHash.calculate(s.getBytes(), 1, 1, 1);
               });
      endTime = System.nanoTime();
      duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
      System.out.println("Finished hashing superfasthash algo (nanoseconds): " + duration );
   }

   private static void writeToArray()
   {
      String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      String toHash;
      Random r = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
      {
         toHash = "";

         for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
         {
            int low = 0;
            int high = 26;
            int result = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
            toHash = toHash + abc.charAt(result);
         }

         dataArray.add(toHash);
         System.out.println("Writing index = " + i + ". String: " + toHash);
      }
   }
}
```

but not sure what to write in the parameter when using the calculate function from SuperFastHash class.

Comment: You should use JMH for microbenchmarks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JimMischel what parameters I should use for the hashing algo

Comment: It kind of depends on which version of SuperFastHash you're using. A Google search reveals https://github.com/Arisotura/Whitehole/blob/master/src/whitehole/SuperFastHash.java, which has a `calculate` method that takes four parameters. Of course, you don't say where you got your `SuperFastHash` class, so I can't be sure if that's the function you're calling. Can't you look at the source code of whatever implementation you have?